# CreateScalableFontResource() call fails in windows 10

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, visual-c++-6

I have an application in which one function creates a XXX.fot file from XXX.ttf file using the "CreateScalableFontResource( 0, szFont, "hel_grid.ttf", szInstall )" call.
This call works fine on Windows 7 but does not work on Windows 10.
Any one has any idea are there any known issues for this functions compatibity with windows 10?
The project was built on VC6.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183517.aspx): *"End of client support: Windows XP"* - You have been living on borrowed time, and finally ran out of luck. Don't let the same happen with your IDE (Visual Studio 6 is almost 20 years old...).

Comment: Then again, MS is usually pretty strong at maintaining backwards compatibility. Perhaps there's a defect in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ttf file is not present in the "szInstall" path, the function fails in Windows 10 and the code progresses. So the solution was to delete or rename the ttf file in the "szInstall" path. If the ttf file is present, the CreateScalableFontResource() function just gets stuck (hangs) and never returns. This was causing my application not to complete the next steps.